# Create a .bat file to run an exe as administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe, administrator

I've created a batch file for running a setup.exe (code below) but I'm having issues getting the setup.exe to "run as administrator". I used [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/make-a-batch-file-to-run-cmd-as-administrator) guide (shortcut trick) for aid.

```
start "" %CD%\Setup.exe
```

NOTE: My files will eventually be burnt to a DVD disk. They are currently in the directory `"C:\Drivers\win8.1_x64\01a.chipset"`.

The batch file code runs the setup.exe (without admin privileges) fine, when running the batch file by itself (i.e. not running the shortcut).

However, when I run the batch file via the shortcut, Windows gives the error `"Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\system32\Setup.exe'"`.

The setup.exe directory is not in the system32 folder. Why does running the batch file find the setup.exe fine but not when I run it by the shortcut (so I can run the setup.exe as an admin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either set the working directory in the shortcut itself, or run Setup.exe not from working directory (`%CD%`) but from directory where script is located:

```
start "" "%~dp0\Setup.exe"
```

Difference from earlier answer is there's no need to `cd` to `%~dp0`. Just run the setup with full path.

Comment: This did the job.
Putting the code `start "" "%~dp0\Setup.exe"` allows the shortcut to run the setup.exe without issue.
I cannot tell if it's running as admin but I think it is as UAC appears.

Comment: This is the only answer I've seen that works without doing the silly shortcut version, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default admin privileged scripts are starting in `C:\Windows\system32\`

Try to put `cd /d "%~dp0"` at the beginning of your script which should [change the work directory](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to the script's one.You can check [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat) if you want to create a shortcut with admin permissions from the command line.